# Trying to pass a variable to the pipeline bypassing foreach in powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm struggling trying to pass a variable not only throughta pipeline but a foreach.

I have in multiples directories a lot of csv files (some with the same name) adding some data to it.

I want to generate a unique csv file merging all files with same name but with one conditions:

- Add an extra column with the date from the above folder I picked up the data

I'm just missing how to pass the variable $outfile to the end of the pipeline (to the Export-CSV function).

```
$mainPath="C:\\....";
$outFilePath = "C:\\Users....\\";
$dateFolder="";
$inputDelimiter=';'
$outputDelimiter=','

$filter="*.csv";
$outFile = "";

Get-ChildItem $mainPath -Recurse -Include $filter `
| %{
        $dateFolder = (Split-Path (Split-Path $_.DirectoryName -Parent )-Leaf)
        $outfile = Split-Path $_ -Leaf
        Import-Csv $_.FullName -Delimiter $inputDelimiter
} `
| Select-Object *,@{Name='Date'; Expression={"$dateFolder"}} `
| Export-Csv $outFilePath$outFile -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter $outputDelimiter
```

Thanks.
Regards.
Jose.

Answer (score 0):

Just move the `Select-Object` and `Export-Csv` statements inside the `ForEach-Object` scriptblock:

```
Get-ChildItem $mainPath -Recurse -Include $filter `
| %{
        $dateFolder = (Split-Path (Split-Path $_.DirectoryName -Parent )-Leaf)
        $outfile = Split-Path $_ -Leaf
        Import-Csv $_.FullName -Delimiter $inputDelimiter `
        | Select-Object *,@{Name='Date'; Expression={"$dateFolder"}} `
        | Export-Csv "$outFilePath$outFile" -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter $outputDelimiter
}
```

Comment: Hi Mathias, thanks for your fast response. It works but breaks something that previously was working... All forlders I have with following structure

/20180101/site1
/20180101/site2
/20180101/site3
....
/20180102/site1
/20180102/site2
/20180102/site3

And I need to have this "date" in a column at the end of each csv with the right parent folder. 
Thanks.